# Firefox 8 throws error on audio (mp3)

Tags: mediaelement.js

Firefox 8 throws the following errors on trying to play

```
pluginMediaElement.pluginElement.Content is undefined
[Break On This Error] pluginMediaElement.pluginApi = plu...pluginElement.Content.MediaElementJS;

Bad NPObject as private data!
[Break On This Error] this.pluginApi.playMedia();
```

The first error occurs on the 8th line below:

```
    // find the javascript bridge
    switch (pluginMediaElement.pluginType) {
        case "flash":
            pluginMediaElement.pluginElement = pluginMediaElement.pluginApi = document.getElementById(id);
            break;
        case "silverlight":
            pluginMediaElement.pluginElement = document.getElementById(pluginMediaElement.id);
            pluginMediaElement.pluginApi = pluginMediaElement.pluginElement.Content.MediaElementJS;
        break;
    }
```

The second error occurs on the 3th line below:

```
// HTML5 methods
play: function () {
    if (this.pluginApi != null) {
        this.pluginApi.playMedia();
        this.paused = false;
    }
},
```

Anyone else encounter this problem and found a way to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Also seeing a lot of "mejs is undefined" errors, might be related (it's not showing where the error is coming from, unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this has something to do with display: none; and flash. Encoding my audio to ogg for Firefox and Opera solved this particular issue (Firefox then uses its native player leaving Flash to the dogs).